# Word switch to suppress blank document on open

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

How can I suppress the creation of a blank word document when users first open Word and enforce this throughout the firm.

**Constraints:** Users won't be able to use command line switches `/n`. I looked at creating shortcuts of Word containing switch, that's not very enforceable at a firm level. This is because users are able to search their start menu for the original Word icon/executable and bypass the shortcut containing the switch.

I didn't see a way to add a switch to the original Word Icon/executable, so I'm left in this dilemma.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you expect to happen instead of a blank document?

Comment: I need to do this to ensure other firm Word AddIns operate as intended. What I expect to happen is to open word without a document open.